# Python - integrate different variables to each user input from a for loop without using list

Tags: python

I need some help here, without using lists and strictly for loop, how do I implement my for loop to insert different variable with different user input?

```
def prompt():
total = int(input("How many books do you have in your basket?  "))
return total

x = prompt()
book = 0
for i in range(x):
book = (float(input('What is the price of book number ' + str(i+1))))
"""    book(i) = book """
```

""" I do not know how to implement the next code to put the book into a different variable to declare that e.g book = book1, book = book2 etc."""

Appreciate if someone can help me out. thanks!

Comment: You should use a `list`.

Comment: Because I am a student and have not learned about list yet, the exercise in my class strictly forbid us to use anything else other than for loop, ifelse and functions and strings

Comment: What, exactly is your expected output. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to get the number of input of books in a basket, from there, the number of books that the user inputs e.g 3, the user input prompt will appear 3 times to ask the price of book 1,2 and 3. i would want to save book 1,2 and 3 or whatever number the user inputs into a variable so i can use to calculate the sum, average .

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misinterpreted the task here? I'd be totally surprised if any course wanted you to use dynamically generated variables at all - let alone before teaching you the concept of a list... are you sure you're not meant to set a total to 0, ask for N many times to loop, loop N many times to get the value, add the value to the total and then print the total and use that total / N originally input to get your average?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create variable here. Here is how you would do the *sum*, I'll leave the average to you:

```
def prompt():
    total = int(input("How many books do you have in your basket?  "))
    return total

total_price = 0

N = prompt()

for i in range(N):
    msg = 'What is the price of book number '+str(i+1)+' '
    price = float(input(msg))
    total_price += price

print("The total price is ", total_price)
```

Creating dynamic variables is generally a very bad practice, and is almost certainly not what your instructor is expecting you to do. Indeed, how would you know how to refer to them? Even if you did do that, it would require using much more arcane things than a `list`.